# Java- function seems to mess up the console, nothing will be printed out after calling the function

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I was asked to program a method that receives a scanner, and returns a sorted array of words which contain only letters, with no repetitions (and no bigger in length than 3000). Then, I was asked to program a method that checks whether a certain given string is contained in a given vocabulary. I used a simple binary search method.
This is what I've done:

```js
public static String[] scanVocabulary(Scanner scanner){       
  String[] array= new String[3000];
  int i=0;
  String word;
  while (scanner.hasNext() && i<3000) {
   word=scanner.next();
   if (word.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
    array[i]=word.toLowerCase();
    i++;
   }
  }int size=0;
  while (size<3000 && array[size]!=null ) {
   size++;
  }
  String[] words=Arrays.copyOf(array, size);
  if (words.length==0 || words.length==1) {
   return words;
  }
  else {
   Arrays.sort(words);
   int end= removeDuplicatesSortedArr(words);
   return Arrays.copyOf(words, end);
  }

 }
 
 private static int removeDuplicatesSortedArr(String[] array) { //must be a sorted array. returns size of the new array
  int n= array.length;
  int j=0;
  for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
   if (!array[i].equals(array[i+1])) {
    array[j++]=array[i];
   }
  }
  array[j++]=array[n-1];
  return j;
 }
 
 public static boolean isInVocabulary(String[] vocabulary, String word){ 
  //binary search
  int n=vocabulary.length;
  int left= 0;
  int right=n-1;
  while (left<=right) {
   int mid=(left+right)/2;
   if (vocabulary[mid].equals(word)){
    return true;
   }
   else if (vocabulary[mid].compareTo(word)>0) {
    right=mid-1;
   }else {
    right=mid+1;
   }
  }
  return false;
 }
```

while trying the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String vocabularyText = "I look at the floor and I see it needs sweeping while my guitar gently weeps";
        Scanner vocabularyScanner = new Scanner(vocabularyText);
        String[] vocabulary = scanVocabulary(vocabularyScanner);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vocabulary));

        boolean t=isInVocabulary(vocabulary, "while");
        System.out.println(t);
        System.out.println("123");

    }
```

I get nothing but-

```
[and, at, floor, gently, guitar, i, it, look, my, needs, see, sweeping, the, weeps, while]
```

nothing else is printed out nor returned. Both functions seem to be working fine separately, so I don't get what I'm doing wrong.
I would be very happy to hear your thoughts, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the console. Your `isInVocabulary` method is entering an infinite loop in this block:

```
    if (!isInVocabulary(vocabulary, "while")) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
```

If you were to debug through `isInVocabulary`, you would see that after a few iterations of the while loop,

```
left = 0;
right = 2;

mid = 1;

if (vocabulary[mid].equals(word)){
    // it doesn't
} else if (vocabulary[mid].compareTo("while") > 0) {
    // it doesn't
} else {
    right = mid + 1;
    // this is the same as saying right = 1 + 1, i.e. 2
}
```

So you'll loop forever.

Comment: Thank you! I totally missed it, it was supposed to be "left" instead of right in the else block- thank you for pointing out! :)

Comment: I'm new to java so I didn't know it was still looping... how embarrassing. thank you :)

Comment: Glad I could be of help!